# Difference between Trusted Platform Module (TPM) and Secure Element (SE)

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

I have been trying to figure out the difference between TPM and SE since last few days. All the answers that I have stumbled upon so far are vague. Both of them are used for cryptographic operation and secure storage of sensitive data like keys. Both are off-chip elements (like a coprocessor?). I want to understand the difference between them at architectural and functional level. Can someone give me a crisp difference between these two components? Unlike most of the Internet answers, I would greatly appreciate if you include links to solid writeups, datasheets in your answer.

Comment: They are two specifications, both standardizing a crypto processor (or "component") but managed by two different groups... It's kinda like asking for the difference between Linux and Windows - they do some things that are similar but in different ways, and then they do some things that are totally different. Functionally, however, one could say that the TPM is more passive, and it can not do as much for you. For example, you can not have a TPM run code in isolation for you, like you can with say Java Cards.

Comment: Can you link the standards you are referring to?